# php - get total of number of results in foreach

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have a foreach loop, that will do a search in my database. I want to get the total number of rows that the search returns.

Currently, I have this:

```
foreach ($stmt as $row) {

    $search=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM advertisement_clicks WHERE username=:username AND token=:token");
    $search->bindParam(":username",$userdata['id']);
    $search->bindParam(":token",$row['token']);
    $search->execute();
    echo $search->rowCount(); 

}
```

This will print out: `00001100` - how can I get the total result of them? (In this case, it would be 2)

Even better, how can I get the total result ***outside*** the foreach loop?

The code outside the loop is this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE status='2' AND fixed='1' AND fixed_expire>:time AND membershipFilter='0'");
$stmt->bindParam(":time",time());
$stmt->execute();
$f=$stmt->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below -

```
$count = 0 ;

foreach ($stmt as $row) {

    $search=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM advertisement_clicks WHERE username=:username AND token=:token");
    $search->bindParam(":username",$userdata['id']);
    $search->bindParam(":token",$row['token']);
    $search->execute();
    $count += $search->rowCount(); 

}

echo $count ;
```

Comment: How you code justify following statement in the question ? (In this case, it would be 2)

Comment: as per his note he is getting 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 in each loop, add them all and u get 2 , this is what exactly the code will do !!

Answer (score 0):

Count it by a variable like htis:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($stmt as $row) {

    $search=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM advertisement_clicks WHERE username=:username AND token=:token");
    $search->bindParam(":username",$userdata['id']);
    $search->bindParam(":token",$row['token']);
    $search->execute();
    $total +=  $search->rowCount(); 


}
```

`$total` will be holding total values.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above participants really understand the meaning of the code they wrote :)
Also, rowCount should never be used for such a purpose, even if in this particular case numbers aren't so high

```
$total  = 0;
$query  = "SELECT count(*) FROM advertisement_clicks 
           WHERE username=:username AND token=:token";
$search = $dbh->prepare($query);
$search->bindParam(":username", $userdata['id']);
$search->bindParam(":token",    $row['token']);

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $search->execute();
    $total += $search->fetchColumn(); 
}
```

it have to be

Also, assuming $stmt is a result of a previous query, most you can get the count already in the other query, by means of using GROUP BY operator. **Without such an extra loop at all**

Comment: why shouldn't rowCount be used? What's the different from that and fetchColumn()

Comment: that's quite obvious. Although you need only count, you are selecting records themselves. Selecting them is a useless load you are burdening your database with. Also check the update I made

Comment: I see that you're using the $row['token'] outside the while loop. I can't do that, as I am checking for whoever has clicked the advertisement.

Comment: But again, you don't need this loop at all

Comment: it doesn't work when I add it to my code. And I can't get it to work. You could try to help me out, and make it without a loop?

Comment: I have updated my question and included the code outside the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($stmt as $row) {

$search=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM advertisement_clicks WHERE username=:username AND token=:token");
   $search->bindParam(":username",$userdata['id']);
   $search->bindParam(":token",$row['token']);
   $search->execute();
   echo $search->rowCount(); 
   $x++;
}
echo $x;
```